# Magento Class not found Issue

Tags: php, html, css, magento

For a few days I am struggling with my `Magento` extension. The developers of that extension are not really helpful as this is a free extension.

I installed: Custom Formbuilder to my `magento` and I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phxsolution_Formbuilder_Block_Adminhtml_Formbuilder_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Text' not found in /home/proliner/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

I don't know really what to do; can anyone help? Here is the code from that line:

```
$block = new $block($attributes);
```

Comment: Did you clear cache?    Does the file app/code/local or community /Phxsolution/Formbuilder/Block/Adminhtml/Formbuilder/Edit/Tab/Options/Type/Text.php  exist?

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for fast reply. Yes, I did clean the cache. Text.php exist however only as a folder. there is no file in it... any idea?

Comment: the error is saying the a class inside a file with above declaration does not exist.

Comment: so what should I do then mate?

Comment: Do you have a link to yhe extensión ?

Comment: Also how did you install it ?

Comment: do you mean developer link? I installed via magento connect manager by the link key.

Comment: here is the link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-formbuilder.html

Comment: Link to extension on connect manager

Comment: One last question. Where is this error displaying

Comment: here is the link: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Phxsolution_Formbuilder

Comment: The error is displaying in the extension when trying to add form and also same error when trying to add custom options in product and in each place where are the custom forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Text.php exist however only as a folder. there is no file in it... any idea?

Due to some -- weird? -- [handling of tar archives in the Magento source code](http://alanstorm.com/magento_connect_from_tar) and on the Magento Connect servers themselves, sometimes the Magento Connect manager will extract a tar archive and **create a folder when it should create a file**.

To fix this I'd

- Manually download the extension archive by pasting the key into [this page](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php?ext=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect20.magentocommerce.com%2Fcommunity%2FPhxsolution_Formbuilder)
- Extract the archive on your local computer and/or another server
- Replace the `Text.php` folder with the `Text.php` file from the manually downloaded archive
- Compare the manually downloaded archive with the other extension files in `app/code/community/Phxsolution/Formbuilder`

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Alan, I was double check and your solution was helpful!!!! Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I new the problem but i didn't know that happened with the connect manager.  I rarely use it